# TestCafe: Page Object Model - accessing all the instantiated objects with a common single reference

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Page model-

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

export default class Page {
    constructor () {
        this.nameInput = Selector('#developer-name');
    }
}
```

Page model2-

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

export default class Page2 {
    constructor () {
        this.nameInput2 = Selector('#tester-name');
    }
}
```

common spec to instantiate the above-

```
import Page from './page-model';
import Page2 from './page-model2';

const page = new Page();
const page2 = new Page2();
```

can we have a single file\spec to instantiate above two Pages and then access all Selectors across Pages from a single reference variable?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create new instances of [page models](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/concepts/page-model.html) in each test, you can export them directly in model.js:

test.js

```
import { pageOne, pageTwo } from './model';

fixture `fixture 1`
    .page `http://example.com`;

test(`test`, async t => {
    await t
    .click(pageOne.el1)
    
    //...navigation to page two
    
    .click(pageTwo.el2);
});
```

model.js

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

class PageOne {
    constructor () {
        this.el1 = Selector('#el1');
        //....
    }
}

class PageTwo {
    constructor () {
        this.el2 = Selector('#el2');
        //....
    }
}

export const pageOne = new PageOne();
export const pageTwo = new PageTwo();
```

**UPDATE**

Also you can organize all selectors in a separate module as follows:

test.js

```
import selectors from './selectors';

fixture `fixture 1`
    .page `http://example.com`;

test(`test`, async t => {
    await t
    .click(selectors.el1)
    .click(selectors.el2);
});
```

selectors.js

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

export default {
    el1: Selector('#el1'),
    el2: Selector('#el2'),
    //....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
But I am looking to have a common reference spec where in i only need to import one function and access the Selectors across multiple files\pages. 
something like this in below- I am not sure if TestCafe allow us to achieve this?

' import { commonSelectorSpec } from './model';

fixture `fixture 1`
    .page `http://example.com`;

test(`test`, async t => {
    await t
    .click(commonSelectorSpec.el1)

    //...navigation to page two

    .click(commonSelectorSpec.el2);
});  '

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. See the updated answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
On top of this can u please suggest how to do it for one more separate page containing the Selectors?